# DirectX : Write to texture with Compute Shader

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm trying to write in a texture with compute shader in HLSL.

Creation of the texture :

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));
textureDesc.Width = 512;
textureDesc.Height = 512;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
m_tex = 0;
hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, 0, &m_tex);
```

Creation of the UAV :

```
D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC descUAV;
ZeroMemory(&descUAV, sizeof(descUAV));
descUAV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
descUAV.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
descUAV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
hr = device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(m_tex, &descUAV, &m_uavAccess);
```

Creation of the SRV (to see the texture) :`

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
srvDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
hr = device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_tex, &srvDesc, &m_srvTexOutput);
```

The shader :

```
RWTexture2D<float4> gOutput : register(u0);

[numthreads(16, 16, 1)]
void main(int3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID) // Thread ID
{
    gOutput[dispatchThreadID.xy] = float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

The problem is that the texture is always black (the compute shader doesn't write to the texture).

Thanks for your help ! :D

Comment: where is your `dispatch` call?

Comment: deviceContext->VSSetShader(NULL, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetShader(NULL, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->CSSetShader(m_computeShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &m_uavAccess, 0);

deviceContext->Dispatch(16, 16, 1);

Comment: Have you tried `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`? Do you unmount UAV and SRV after you use them?

Comment: Also judging by your thread group count and `numthreads` you're only covering 1/4 of the texture, which of course doesn't explain the fact the texture is completely black.  How do you check that by the way? Can you share the render code?

Comment: I render the texture on a quad with this pixel shader : `float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
 return shaderTexture.Sample(SampleTypePoint, input.tex);
}
` This works with an other texture.

Comment: Well if it works then the compute shader is indeed the culprit, what about `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` then?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you need to cause the GPU to flush the surface before using it as an input in a different shader invocation (draw/PS). You do this by binding a null resource to the previous shader stage.

```
    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView *NullUav = nullptr;
    m_DeviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &NullUav, nullptr);
```

This should be enough to tell the graphics driver to flush or transition the resource from a write to a read resource.

If you use D3D12 or vulkan you will need a resource barrier when going from write to read.

Example render loop:

```
    // Run compute kernel output to UAV.
    m_DeviceContext->CSSetShader(m_ComputeShader, NULL, 0);
    m_DeviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &m_UAV, nullptr);
    m_DeviceContext->Dispatch(DispatchX, DispatchY, DispatchZ);

    // Run the raster pipeline to present the UAV values to screen.
    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView *NullUav = nullptr;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* NullSrv = nullptr;
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *NullDsv = nullptr;
    m_DeviceContext->PSSetShader(m_PixelShader, NULL, 0);
    m_DeviceContext->VSSetShader(m_VertexShader, NULL, 0);
    m_DeviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &NullUav, nullptr);
    m_DeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_SRV);
    m_DeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_IndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    m_DeviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_SamplerState);
    m_DeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RenderTarget, NullDsv);
    m_ViewPort.Width = (float)RTWidth;
    m_ViewPort.Height = (float)RTHeight;
    m_ViewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    m_DeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_ViewPort);
    m_DeviceContext->DrawIndexed(4, 0, 0);

    //  Present the final result.
    int Result = m_SwapChain->Present(1, 0);
    if (Result == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || Result == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET) {
        // Reinitialize the renderer..
    }

    // Unset the SRV
    m_DeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &NullSrv);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I bound an UAV and a SRV on the same texture.

I resolved the problem creating two textures : one bound to an UAV and another bound to a SRV.

The compute shader write on the UAV and, each frame, I copy the data on the SRV with `deviceContext->CopyResource(m_texSRV, m_texUAV);`

The problem now is the performance, `CopyResource` is a costly operation. Does it have an other solution less expensive ?

Thanks for your help ! :D

Comment: You most definitely do not need two separate textures, this is a costly workaround. Again, you need to debug your graphics with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG which will probably show that you don't  reset UAV and/or SRV after `Dispatch` and `DrawPrimitive` or if it's not the case it will let you debug your shaders.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm running into the same thing with D3D12. There are Zero errors with debug layers etc. I can see the GPU usage go up from compute shader but its just black when I sample from it.